# Can't import class from the same package

Tags: java, import, package, symbols

I am new to Java and can't find my mistake, the compiler gives me this error message:

```
->javac B.java
B.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import a0.A;
         ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: package a0
```

My classes are really simple:

```
package a0;

import a0.A;

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Class B

```
package a0;

public class A {
}
```

Class A

I work under Ubuntu 16.04, both classes are in the same directory.

Comment: Build error? Are there any compile errors in `A`?

Comment: No, that is the only error I get

Comment: Did you specify location of your package in classpath?

Comment: Both files are in the same directory

Comment: Try with `javac -cp .;.. B.java` (`;` may need to be replaced with `:` depending on OS).

Comment: @Pshemo your parameters did not change anything

Comment: What is location from which you are trying to execute this command? (it works for me on Windows 8.1 if I execute `javac -cp .;.. B.java` from `a0` directory containing `B.java`.

Comment: I execute it in the directory both .java files are.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `;` with `:`?

Comment: Yes, `;` wouldn't work under my OS anyway :)

Comment: Hmm. I am just guessing here, but maybe your compiler doesn't automatically compile source of imported classes (it will search for `A.class` file, and for me if it can't find it it will try to generate it from `A.java`). So try first compiling `A.java`, then `B.java`.

Comment: Try `javac a0/B.java` from the directory containing a0.

Comment: @JamesKPolk `javac: file not found a0/B.java`

Comment: Your B.java (and A.java) file should be inside the a0 directory given your package structure.

Comment: Did you execute it from directory *containing* `a0` package?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I recreated your directory/file structure in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_terminal_online.php and `javac -cp .:.. B.java` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import classes on the same package!

Comment: While what you are saying it is true and that is how we should normally write our code, it is still not prohibited, so real problem is somewhere else (most probably lack of proper classpath).

Comment: @Pshemo That's what I thought, too. Do you have any idea how I could specify my error further?

Comment: @Jonas Error means that compiler is not able to locate `A.class` in `a0` package (directory). So either location of that package is not in classpath OP is using, or used compiler is not able to compile `A.java` on the fly when needed. I don't have installed Ubuntu with Java so can't test it.

Comment: @Jonas, you have to specify that a0 is a package. javac a0/B.java will work when running from a directory above.